# Next.JS, Does `force-dynamic` in route handler removes data cache too?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this route handler with `GET` request:

```
export async function GET(_: Request, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
```

[From the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#opting-out-of-caching), we can actually opt out of caching using force dynamic, adding this will invalidate the cache:

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

However, from the [caching docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache-and-full-route-cache), it mentions that:

> Invalidating or opting out of the Full Route Cache does not affect the Data Cache.

So in the route handler case, do I need to opt out of BOTH full route cache and data cache (at the fetch level)?